# How to convert complex emoji to unicde?

Tags: java, unicode, stanford-nlp, emoji

For example,

```
good flavor
```

When I copy this string to Java code, it automatically becomes:

```
String str = EmojiParser.removeAllEmojis("good flavor\uD83D\uDC4D\uD83C\uDffB):
```

I am working in IntelliJ. The automatically converted string after copying can pass my code in an external library (stanford parser-chinese) I am using.

However, if I directly reads in from a file and apply the same function above, it only coverts the first two codes "\uD83D\uDC4D". The rest "\u83C\uDffB" wasn't removed by the function and thus failed my code in the library.

In Java, how to convert this compound emoji into unicode so my code can pass safely? It would be good enough if it can be converted into the same format as the what I copied to the code.

As a matter of fact, not only emojis, some other non-standard unicode characters may have same issues, and I am dealing with Asian languages.

**EDIT:**

```
public List<CoreMap> annotate(@Nonnull final String document) {
            Annotation annotation = new Annotation(EmojiParser.removeAllEmojis(document));
            this.annotate(annotation);
            List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);
            if(sentences==null){
                return new ArrayList<CoreMap>();
            }
            return sentences;
        }
```

In this code, for the above String, the 'annotation.get()' will return "null", which shouldn't do that. So I need to pre-format the 'document' string before sending it to the 'new Annodation()' method.

**EDIT 2:** Read data from file:

```
BufferedReader br = null;
        List<Document> processedDocs = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            if (location == DataLocation.relativeToResources) {
                br = new BufferedReader(IOUtils.fileReaderAsResource(filePath));
            } else if (location == DataLocation.relativeToRoot) {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath)));
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException("Unknown data location! " + location);
            }
            String line;
            int docNo = 0;
            List<Future<Document>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                line = line.trim();
                if (line.isEmpty()) {
                    continue;
                }
                Callable<Document> callable = null;
                callable = new NLPThread(line, filePath, ++docNo, docSource);

                if (callable != null) {
                    tasks.add(s_pool.submit(callable));
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you provide the source where you read in the data and where exactly your problem is?

Comment: Did correcting the typo make the problem go away?

Comment: Also, if you're using the Vincent Durmont library, it comes with a JSON file that lists all the emojis that it recognises.  You could check that your emojis are in the JSON file.

Comment: I think https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toCodePoint(char,%20char) is the answer but I'm not sure without seeing the code I asked for

Comment: You added some code but not the one actually reading in the data into a String.

Comment: @Lothar See Edit 2. It's just the regular way to read data in from a file.

Comment: `new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath))` without providing a charset as second parameter, uses the system's charset like Cp1252 on a Windows-system. This most likely will lead to corrupt characters in your String. Same for `FileReader` BTW. Because you can't provide a charset with `FileReader` I never understood why it actually exists.

Comment: I added this "new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))" and see how it goes? Thanks.

Comment: Is `location == DataLocation.relativeToRoot`? If not, you're creating the FileReader with the same problem

Comment: Yes. I will add charset=utf-8 in all possibilities.